# Value of one field in a struct becomes value of another field unintentionally

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a struct that will carry data of a restaurant order for home delivery.

This is my header file named `order.h`:

```
#ifndef ORDER_H
#define ORDER_H


extern long orderNumber;


typedef struct {

    long orderNumber;
    char *customerName;
    long customerContactNumber;
} *Order;



Order newOrder();
void setCustomerName(Order, char *);
void setCustomerContactNumber(Order, long);


#endif
```

And my source file with implementation of method from the header file is below named `order.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "order.h"


long orderNumber = 0;


Order newOrder() {


    orderNumber++;

    Order order = (Order)malloc(sizeof(Order));
    order->orderNumber = orderNumber;

    return order;
}



void setCustomerName(Order order, char *customerName) {

    order->customerName = customerName;
}



void setCustomerContactNumber(Order order, long customerContactNumber) {

    order->customerContactNumber = customerContactNumber;
}
```

And my file containing the main method is `main.c`:

```
#include "order.h"
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {

    void displayOrder(Order);
    Order order1 = newOrder();
    Order order2 = newOrder();
    Order order3 = newOrder();

    setCustomerName(order1, "Aditya R.Singh");
    setCustomerContactNumber(order1, 123L);

    setCustomerName(order2, "Rameshwarpratap R.Singh");
    setCustomerContactNumber(order2, 456L);

    setCustomerName(order3, "Sarita R.Singh");
    setCustomerContactNumber(order3, 789L);

    displayOrder(order1);
    displayOrder(order2);
    displayOrder(order3);

    return 0;
}  




void displayOrder(Order order) {

    long id = order->orderNumber;
    char *name = order->customerName;
    long contactNumber = order->customerContactNumber;

    fprintf(stdout, "==========================================\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "Order number: %ld\n", id);
    fprintf(stdout, "Customer Name: %s\n", name);
    fprintf(stdout, "Customer Contact Number: %ld\n", contactNumber);
    fprintf(stdout, "==========================================\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\n\n");

    fflush(stdout);
}
```

The expected output is:

```
==========================================
Order number: 1
Customer Name: Aditya R.Singh
Customer Contact Number: 123
==========================================



==========================================
Order number: 2
Customer Name: Rameshwarpratap R.Singh
Customer Contact Number: 456
==========================================



==========================================
Order number: 3
Customer Name: Sarita R.Singh
Customer Contact Number: 789
==========================================
```

But the actual output is:

```
==========================================
Order number: 1
Customer Name: Aditya R.Singh
Customer Contact Number: 123
==========================================



==========================================
Order number: 123
Customer Name: Rameshwarpratap R.Singh
Customer Contact Number: 456
==========================================



==========================================
Order number: 456
Customer Name: Sarita R.Singh
Customer Contact Number: 789
==========================================
```

As you can notice, `orderNumber` of `order2` is overwritten by `customerContactNumber` of `order1`.

And `orderNumber` of `order3` is overwritten by `customerContactNumber` of `order2`.

Why is this happening?
How am I supposed to get the expected output?

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line where you allocate memory is wrong.

```
Order order = (Order)malloc(sizeof(Order));
```

`sizeof(order)` is size of a pointer, not the size of the `struct`.  Everything after is subject to undefined behavior.

To fix the problem, you can use:

```
Order order = (Order)malloc(sizeof(*order));
```

Problems like this can be avoided by using better `typedef`s. Instead of

```
typedef struct {
  long orderNumber;
  char *customerName;
  long customerContactNumber;
} *Order;
```

It's better to use:

```
typedef struct {
  long orderNumber;
  char *customerName;
  long customerContactNumber;
} Order;

typedef Order* OrderPtr;
```

These will cause less confusion about the type of the variables.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
Order order = (Order)malloc(sizeof(Order));
```

You have defined `Order` as

```
typedef struct {
  long orderNumber;
  char *customerName;
  long customerContactNumber;
} *Order;
```

which is a pointer type and the previous allocation allocates space for one pointer. A correct allocation shall be something like:

```
    Order order = (Order)malloc(sizeof(*order));
```